# Config Dependent Observers

Tags: event-observer, configuration

Via layout.xml you can add the node `ifconfig` that will allow for the admin to enable/disable parts of an extension. An example is in the sales section:

```
ifconfig="sales/msrp/enabled"
```

My question is, without adding a check to all my observer methods in a module, is there a way have a similar flag on observers?

Example is if you had a module that does one thing on an observer but you want to disable this on a store level.

Comment: Not possible unless your rewrite the `Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent`. See how that method works. I guess you have to put the verification inside your observer.

Comment: boo, that is a shame feels odd wrapping each part with the same check :(

Comment: I know. But those are the rules. take it or leave it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as pointed out by Marius there is no built in way of doing this :( There are two options for making this sort of thing happen.

1. Rewrite how the function `dispatchEvent` works to check for this sort of flag on each item,
2. Just continue to check on each observer function itself,

I will stick with the second option as I really don't want to be be changing how `Mage_Core_Model_App` works. Though it may be an idea that could be looked into at a hackathon or a boring evening after the World Cup is over.

Answer (score 0):

This can be reference:

File:

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php

```
    protected function _generateAction($node, $parent) {

      if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifconfig'])) {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
            return $this;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware how the layout does this but my question was if/how it would be possible for observers.

Comment: I am not sure it does